# HSQLDB Manager?

Tags: user-interface, hsqldb

I have tried SQLite in Java, but the speed is slow due to the JDBC driver. Then I tried HSQLDB and thought the speed is good, but I cannot find a good management tool for HSQLDB such as phpMyAdmin for MySQL or [SQLite Manager](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/5817) for SQLite.

I'd like to use the manager tool to prepare the test data for unit tests, or use the manager tool to navigate the data after doing some small experiments.

Is there any good tool?

Answer (score 13):

Here are a couple other suggestions you might checkout:

- Squirrel SQL http://squirrel-sql.sourceforge.net/
- Execute Query http://executequery.org/
- Razor SQL (paid) http://www.razorsql.com/

Razor has the best feature set, but is paid.  The others are good at different things and worth checking into.

Comment: @ShantanuKumar Now they have a free version :)

Answer (score 4):

This would only have meaning if you are running in HSQLDB server mode. If you are running in memory or file mode, then you either can't access the DB from another process or doing so would lock it.

In Server mode you could use any universal client. JDBC driver is the hsqldb.jar itself.

Answer (score 3):

Actually HSQL brings its own management tool (which is not super). See http://hsqldb.org/doc/guide/apf.html

Answer (score 2):

I've used Squirrel SQL. It's a universal client for any JDBC database.

See: http://squirrel-sql.sourceforge.net/